# Can a Hypnotism target be forced to move before its attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, wizard

I have just created a Wizard (Mage) who specializes in enchantment.  I have a question about the Hypnotism spell..

The power states that the target creature can be forced to attack another enemy (or itself apparently).  If there are no other creatures adjacent to the monster can it move to attack another creature, and if so, what is the range of its movement?

Comment: You might want to split off your question about increasing attack bonus to hit into a seperate question.  It keeps things far cleaner that way

Comment: I agree with Phil, I've edited your second question out as it's not related to the first. Please feel free to ask about increasing the wizard's attack bonus at low levels.

Answer (score 10):

The hypnotism power's hit line reads as follows:

> Choose one of the following effects:
>
> - The target uses a free action to make a melee basic attack against a creature with a +4 bonus to the attack roll.
> - You slide the target up to 3 squares.

(HOTFL 205)

This means that you can only cause the target to attack or to move, not both. The attack is a Melee Basic Attack which requires an attack roll like a normal MBA.

Note that charge is not a valid use in this situation, unless the creature's MBA specifically allows for charging.